# PlotRange prevents PlotLabels from displaying

Tags: plotting, labeling

(I am using MMA v.12.0.0 OSX.)

It seems like `PlotRange` is preventing `PlotLabels` from displaying the labels of the curve which have the same last data value.

I actually got this problem with `DateListLogPlot` but it seems to happen for different kind of plots.

Here is simple example with `ListLinePlot` :

```
data = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 5}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 5}, {4, 5, 
6, 7, 8}};

ListLinePlot[data, PlotLabels -> {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

but

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 5.5}, All}, 
PlotLabels -> {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

and I don't like this workaround with `PlotRangePadding` (the labels are at the right position but the lines (leaders) are too short as they stop at the frame) :

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1}, Automatic}, 
PlotLabels -> {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Place the labels: `ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 5.5}, All}, 
 PlotLabels -> Placed[Range[4], Scaled[0.5]], Frame -> True]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, I've tried that but I want the labels to be in a column out of the frame (because I have many  curves and the plot is crowded). I just want what would be expected in the second plot.

Comment: @BobHanlon Sorry, i was not clear in the post concerning the position of the labels, i corrected it ("the labels are at the right position but the lines (leaders) are too short as they stop at the frame")

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 5}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 5}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 
    8}};
```

The problem with the labels is caused by the final data values being the same. As a workaround, even a negligible offset (`10^-6` in this case) eliminates the problem.

```
data2 = ReplacePart[data, {
    2 -> data[[2]] + 10.^-6,
    3 -> data[[3]] - 10.^-6}];

ListLinePlot[data2, PlotRange -> {{0, 5.5}, All}, PlotLabels -> Range[4], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: ); yes I thought about it but in my real life case I have many curves, regularly updated, I use tooltip to show the data values, and I display some of them ... so it would add some extra work. I would prefer not to modify the data but it seems that it will be the only workaround ...

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing Bob Hanlon's approach and coloring labels and callout curves to match the color of corresponding lines:

```
ClearAll[jitterEndPoint, colorCallouts]

jitterEndPoint[epsilon_: 10^-5] := MapAt[# + RandomReal[{-epsilon, epsilon}] &, #, 
  {All, -1}] &;

colorCallouts = # /. GraphicsGroup[a_] :> GraphicsGroup[Replace[a, b_BSplineCurve :>
    Style[b, Thin, Cases[a, Rotate[Style[_, col_, ___], ___] :> col, All]],  All]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
data = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 5}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 5}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};

Row[{#, colorCallouts@#2}] & @@ (ListLinePlot[# @ data, 
     PlotLabels -> (Style[#, ColorData[97]@#, 12] & /@ Range[Length@data]),
     ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 5.5}, All}] & /@ {Identity, jitterEndPoint[]})
```

[image]

```
Row[{#, colorCallouts@#2}] & @@ (ListLinePlot[# @ data, 
     PlotLabels -> (Style[#, ColorData[97]@#, 12] & /@ Range[Length@data]),
     ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 10.5}, All}] & /@ {Identity, jitterEndPoint[]})
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
dt = RandomInteger[100, {10, 5}];
dt[[;; 7, -1]] = 70;
dt[[8 ;;, -1]] = 30;

Row[{#, colorCallouts@#2}] & @@ (ListLinePlot[# @ dt, 
     PlotLabels -> (Style[#, ColorData[97]@#, 12] & /@ Range[Length@dt]),
     ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 5.5}, All}] & /@ {Identity, jitterEndPoint[]})
```

[image]

With default setting for `PlotRange` we do not need jittering but coloring labels and/or callouts still helps:

```
Row[{#, colorCallouts@#}, Spacer[10]] & @
 ListLinePlot[data,  ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True,
    PlotLabels -> (Style[#, ColorData[97]@#, 12] & /@ Range[Length@data])]
```

[image]

```
Row[{#, colorCallouts@#}, Spacer[10]] & @
 ListLinePlot[dt,  ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True,
    PlotLabels -> (Style[#, ColorData[97]@#, 12] & /@ Range[Length@dt])]
```

[image]